# Setting a datetime relative to UTC_TIMESTAMP()

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to set a datetime field in MySQL relative to UTC_TIMESTAMP(). E.g., if I want to set it to 1 hour in the past, is there some equivalent of

```
UPDATE table_name set datetime_col=(UTC_TIMESTAMP()-3600) where ...
```

(If I try the above it sets the datetime field to 00-00-0000 00:00:00)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
 UPDATE table_name set datetime_col=DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Comment: though strictly it should be subtracting from UTC_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1):

```
DATE_ADD(UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add